# drupal 8, create a list of referenced content B from the 'main' content A

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

In drupal 8, I created a content (type A) who contain a reference to another type (B) of content.
When I add a new content A, the form allow add a list of reference to contents B (if a content B has been created)

Is there a way (no programmatically, via the admin page or a contrib module) who allow create the list of content B when I add a content A ?

Actually, I must create a list of content B, then I create a content A and I add the list of reference of content B
I would like, create a list of content B from the new content A

If there is only the programmatically way, have you an example for implement what I want ?

Thank you =)

Comment: I don't quite understand your aim here? When you are creating Content A you want Content B to already be created? Or is it just that you want a field, when editing a node to show a list of the other nodes? If it is the latter, you can use the 'Manage fields' > 'Reference' > 'Content' field which allows you to create references between nodes or other objects like users, etc

Comment: Sorry for my bad english x) When I go to the page "create content A", I want to create contents B in the same page, and add the reference between the content A and contents B. Now, I do that in two steps, first, I must create some content B (page "create content B"), second, I must create a content A (page "create content A") and add references to contents B. I want one only step, I create a new content A, from the page "create content A", I want to be able to create immediately a liste of contents B and contents B are automatically added as reference to the content A